# How do I make an emoji macro keyboard for linux?

Tags: keyboard-shortcuts, macro, emoji

I want to make a macro keyboard that types emoji for my Raspberry Pi 4 with a quite old spare keyboard. I got this idea from Tom Scott (British youtuber) and he made it in windows.

Although I could just find bare minimum info for how you can make it in Linux but I got some info about autohotkey and Luamacros but none of them work on Linux!!

So if any of you could kindly provide me info about any other alternatives of the above programs that can run on Linux and provide  the same result and take up maximum 20mb of space and how I can program my keyboard to get it to type emojis on Linux (in my case Raspbian)

I tried nothing over here just because I want to do it in one take.

Comment: ibus has emoji input facility.

Comment: Hey @AbdullahIbnFulan could you please tell how I can implement it? Thank you. I found little videos and information  about ibus emoji but its not enough for me to understand  how to implement it....thanks again Abdullah, which is my cousins name too

Comment: Ibus insert emoji with shortcut ctrl+shift+u. That should work with unicode emoji short names https://unicode.org/emoji/charts/emoji-list.html. There is also a ibus input method to do so. https://github.com/salty-horse/ibus-uniemoji